# Gulp error - 'No path specified! Can not get relative.'

Tags: gulp

I using Gulp in my project in Visual Studio 2013.

I moved all my projects to new dev-machine. In project I use Gulp. Here is my task in gulpfile.js:

```
    config = {
        scripts: {
            src: "./app",
            destination: "./scripts/app"
        },
        templates: {
            src: "./app/**/*.tmpl.html",
            destination: "./scripts/app",
            filename: "templates"
        },
        build: {
            src: "./scripts/app/*.js",
            destination: "./scripts/build",
            filename: "dashboard-build"
        }
    }

  gulp.task("templates", function () {
    gulp.src(config.templates.src)
        .pipe(html2js({
            outputModuleName: "templates",
            useStrict: true
        }))
        .pipe(concat(config.templates.filename + ".js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.templates.destination))
});
```

When I try to fire the task command prompt window I get this error:

```
C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web>gulp templates
[17:04:59] Using gulpfile C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\gulpfile.js
[17:04:59] Starting 'templates'...
[17:04:59] Finished 'templates' after 12 ms
C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\vinyl\index.js:120
    if (!this.path) throw new Error('No path specified! Can not get relative.');
                    ^

Error: No path specified! Can not get relative.
    at File.get (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\vinyl\index.js:120:27)
    at Stream.bufferContents (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-concat\index.js:35:20)
    at Stream.stream.write (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-concat\node_modules\through\index.js:26:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:531:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:198:18)
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.push (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:157:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform.push (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:123:32)
    at DestroyableTransform._flush (C:\Development\Repositories\Tambaound\Tambaound.Web\node_modules\gulp-html2js\index.js:75:14)
```

While on my old machine all worked perfectly and all other tasks on new dev machine works fine. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using different versions of `gulp-html2js` on those two machines.

The following is an example taken straight from the [`README.md` for v0.3.1](https://github.com/fraserxu/gulp-html2js/tree/8156d60deadac3200fd86deaa70ebb55c74d51a3#usage) of `gulp-html2js`:

```
gulp.src('templates/*.html')
  .pipe(html2js({
     outputModuleName: 'template-test',
     useStrict: true,
     target: 'js'
  }))
```

That looks very much like the code you're trying to use.

However here's the same example taken from the [`README.md` for v0.4.2](https://github.com/fraserxu/gulp-html2js/tree/a09dea5ca88babddb42aed8805ccb199e5e79270#usage) (latest version):

```
gulp.src('templates/*.html')
  .pipe(html2js('angular.js', {
     adapter: 'angular',
     base: 'templates',
     name: 'angular-demo'
  }))
```

Notice the difference? The `ouputModuleName` option seems to have been renamed to `name`. Also the first parameter for `html2js()` is now the filename for the new module. Your code is missing that and that's what's giving you the `No path specified!` error.

Normally something like this shouldn't happen. Modules should follow [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) and breaking changes like this should only be introduced in major version changes. However v0.x.x [is exempt from this rule](http://semver.org/#spec-item-4):

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

You have two options:

1. Make sure you install the same version of `gulp-html2js` that you have on the old machine. Using v0.3.1 should do it:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev gulp-html2js@0.3.1
   ```
2. Adjust your task to look like the one in the example for version 0.4.2 above. The [README for that version](https://github.com/fraserxu/gulp-html2js/tree/a09dea5ca88babddb42aed8805ccb199e5e79270) should help you with that.

(You might also want to look into using [`gulp-ng-html2js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-html2js) instead, which is a competing plugin that seems to be doing the same task, but has about three times as many downloads.)